# how to set mail quota size of a registered user in ibm domino using notes api

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I want to increase and decrease email quota of a already registered user in IBM domino.I can do the same from domino administrator but i want to do it using notes API .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NotesDatabase's property [SizeQuota](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/de/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SIZEQUOTA_PROPERTY.html) and [SizeWarning](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/de/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SIZEWARNING_PROPERTY_DB.html)

Example: set quota to 100MB and warning to 70 MB

```
  Dim db As NotesDatabase
  Set db = ...get user's mail database...
  db.SizeQuota = 100000
  db.SizeWarning = 70000
```

Comment: Take care: You need to respect the order. If you increase the quota, you need to set Quota  BEFORE Warning, if you decrease it, you have to decrease Warning BEFORE Quota, as Warning is not allowed to be larger than quota at any time...

Comment: Thank you sir for your help...i have created java code using notes api with the help of your answer and it works